# tabular, siunitx and input - `Extra }, or forgotten $.`

Tags: tables, errors, input, siunitx

I'm trying to include data into a tabular environment

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}
      \toprule
      {$na^3$} & {$V_0/T_c^0$} & {$T_c/T_c^0$} & {$\nu$} \\
      \midrule
      \input{../results/110718/all.tex}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{bla}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

On compiling I get the error message `Extra }, or forgotten $.`

When I insert `all.tex` manually, it works:

```
% ...      
      \midrule
      0 & 0 & 0.99959(72) & 0.882(44) \\
      % ...
      5e-3 & 2 & 1.02710(66) & 0.757(73) \\
      5e-3 & 7 & 0.53844(100) & 0.75(10) \\
      \bottomrule
% ...
```

Just copy paste, `all.tex` already contains the ampersands and backslashes.

When I don't use `siunitx`, it works, too:

```
% ...
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \toprule
      {$na^3$} & {$V_0/T_c^0$} & {$T_c/T_c^0$} & {$\nu$} \\
      \midrule
      \input{../results/110718/all.tex}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
% ...
```

`booktabs` doesn't seem to cause the issue. It still doesn't work when I remove the `booktabs` rules.

The file `all.tex` is generated automatically. Thus, including it manually is not really an option. And because of the nice formatting capabilities of `siunitx` I would really like to use it.

I'm using TeX-Live 2011-05-26.

What causes this error and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the S style will allow you to input files (\input isn't expanded before parsing of the contents begin). This table can be quite easily produced by `pgfplotstable` if you are willing to slightly modify the way all.tex is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mikael has commented, the problem here is to do with getting the numbers expanded. In standard mode, `siunitx` needs to collect up the number before it typesetting it. The trick is to use an additional column. This will work without any extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{filecontents*}{all.tex}
& 1.1 & 2.2 & 3.3 & 4.4 \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{}SSSS}
      \toprule
      & {$na^3$} & {$V_0/T_c^0$} & {$T_c/T_c^0$} & {$\nu$} \\
      \midrule
      \input{all.tex}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{bla}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

There is an example in the `siunitx` manual using `datatool` which does a similar thing but uses data in CSV format. Adapting it here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool,siunitx}
\begin{filecontents*}{all.csv}
valuea,valueb,valuec,valued
1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{data}{all.csv}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS@{}l}
      \toprule
      {$na^3$} & {$V_0/T_c^0$} & {$T_c/T_c^0$} & {$\nu$}  &
        \DTLforeach{data}
          {\myvaluea=valuea,\myvalueb=valueb,\myvaluec=valuec,\myvalued=valued}{%
          \DTLiffirstrow {\\ \midrule}{\\}%
          \myvaluea & \myvalueb & \myvaluec & \myvalued &
        }
      \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{bla}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you do  not want to use an additional column, then turn off the `siunitx` number parser:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{filecontents*}{all.tex}
1.1 & 2.2 & 3.3 & 4.4 \\
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$na^3$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$V_0/T_c^0$} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{$T_c/T_c^0$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu$} \\
      \midrule
      \input{all.tex}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{bla}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I chose the first solution. Adding an additional column to the data file is an easy fix. The typeset result looks exactly identical to including the data manually without an additional column.