# LaTeX's datatool package together with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, datatool, colortbl

I want to use the `datatool` package to read csv files and parse them to LaTeX tables. Furthermore I want to use `siunitx` to format the numbers from the csv file.
Have a look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%% table data
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age,IQ
Albert,Einstein,133,210.12
Marie,Curie,145,220.12
\end{filecontents*}

%%% table design
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{black!60}
\newcommand\tableheadfont{
  \sffamily\bfseries
  \slshape
  \color{white}
}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{table}{scientists.csv}


\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker
         }
\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{white!100}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l
                l
                S[table-format = 3.0  ,round-precision=0]
                S[table-format = 3.2  ,round-precision=2]
                @{}l}
    \rowcolor{tableheadcolor}
    \tableheadfont name & \tableheadfont surname & \tableheadfont age & \tableheadfont iq & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \DTLforeach*{table}%
    {\name=name, \surname=surname, \age=age, \iq=IQ}%
    {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
     \name & \surname & \age & \iq &
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The last column contains a numerical value which shall be formatted with `siunitx` (S-column). That's why I had to append an empty row (have a look at [tabular, siunitx and input - `Extra }, or forgotten $.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/tabular-siunitx-and-input-extra-or-forgotten) for details).

here is the result:
[image]

There are two problems with this solution:

1. due to the colored header the last header cell isn't complete (the q is missing)
2. the "Albert" in the first data cell is shifted to the right.

Does anybody know how I can solve these problems?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have taken the liberty of doing minor cosmetic edits to your post, like [inline code marking](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), I hope you don't mind..

Comment: The shift of ‘Albert’ is due to a missing `%` after `\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}`. I don't see an incomplete header, can you add a picture?

Comment: Same here, No incomplete header. May be you should update!

Comment: Hi,thanks i corrected the shifted albert. and i added a picture. The "q" if iq is missing in the header.

Answer (score 7):

Both simple problems. The misplacement of 'Albert' is as mentioned in a comment due to a missing `%`:

```
\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
```

The odd business with the `q` is caused by having `& \tabularnewline` at the end of the header row, which mis-places things. Try instead just `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%% table data
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age,IQ
Albert,Einstein,133,210.12
Marie,Curie,145,220.12
\end{filecontents*}

%% table design
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{black!60}
\newcommand\tableheadfont{%
  \sffamily\bfseries
  \slshape
  \color{white}
}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{table}{scientists.csv}


\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker
         }

\begin{tabular}{l
                l
                S[table-format = 3.0  ,round-precision=0]
                S[table-format = 3.2  ,round-precision=2]
                @{}l}
    \rowcolor{tableheadcolor}
    \tableheadfont name & \tableheadfont surname & \tableheadfont age & \tableheadfont the long iq  \\
    \hline
    \DTLforeach*{table}%
    {\name=name, \surname=surname, \age=age, \iq=IQ}%
    {\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
     \name & \surname & \age & \iq &
    }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Yes that works, but there is another problem: in my original table i have alternating rowcolors (with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{white!100}`). In this case there is also the end of each line missing and not only the header. This can't be resolved with your solution because datatool throws an error if the line is not complete. (i added this to the first post)

Comment: @Jonas Add `\rowcolor{gray!15}` after the `\hline` and add `\DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{gray!15}}{\rowcolor{white!100}}` after `\tabularnewline` (before the closing brace) and that should do it.